# AWS Amplify Nested Query does not return anything

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I developed a food delivery service app with 4 frontends (2*react-app & 2*react-native apps) with AWS Amplify. Unfortunately i am facing bad issues in my react apps for nested queries using aws-amplify v5.0.2

When i query nested data in my react frontends unfortunately the nested model sometimes does not delivery any data => not error os thrown the response is undefined...

Schema

```
type OrderDish @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  quantity: Int!
  Dish: Dish @hasOne
  orderID: ID! @index(name: "byOrder")
}

type Dish @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  image: String
  description: String!
  shortDescription: String
  price: Float!
  restaurantID: ID! @index(name: "byRestaurant")
  soldOut: Boolean
  category: DishCategory @hasOne
  allergens: [Allergens]
}
```

My react code:

```
/**
 * Fetching OrderDish
 */
useEffect(() => {
  if (!order?.id) {
    return;
  }

  DataStore.query(OrderDish, (o) => o.orderID.eq(order.id)).then(
    setOrderDishes
  );
}, [order?.id]);
```

With the orderDishes i render a List using AntDesign:

```
<List
   dataSource={orderDishes}
   renderItem={(d) => <OrderDishItem key={d.id} orderDishItem={d} 
   />}
/>
```

Within the OrderDishItem i query the Dish as this is an AsyncItem of OrderDish. By the way, i wish this would be Eager instead of Lazy, but there is actually no way to get this working unless i downgrade the aws-amply version.

OrderDishItem:

```
function fetchDish() {
  setDishError(false);
  setLoading(true);

  orderDishItem?.Dish?.then((d) => {
    if (d) {
      setTheDish(d);
    } else {
      setDishError("Dish is Empty"); // WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN
    }
  })
    .catch((error) => setDishError(error?.message || true))
    .finally(() =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 500)
    );
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchDish();
}, [orderDishItem?.Dish]);
```

So in fetchDish the Dish returns always undefined, until i completely logout of the react app. During logout i call DataStore.stop() & DataStore.clear() & DataStore.start() which fixes the problem. Basically restarting the DataStore service and then everything is fine again...

Is there anyone who had the same issues and found out how to fix this?